# PyCharm: Weird auto-indentation of multiline Python comments

Tags: comments, pycharm

When I type comments over multiple lines in PyCharm it auto-indents them like this:

```
# A comment
        # that goes
        # over multiple lines
```

I can manually remove the indentation, but is there a way to configure PyCharm to not do this?

---

Edit: This happens after an earlier line that expects indentation. For example:

```
if(a == 3):
    do_something()

# I start a (non-indented) comment for some code after the if,
    # but then it auto-indents the next line
```

To be honest, it's not the end of the world. But if there is a setting to make it cleverer about this, that would be great!

Comment: I don't see a problem. Mind giving us a video or demo of some sort for what you're doing? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific about when this occurs.

Comment: Again, why version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: Sorry - version 3.01 Build #PC-131.339

Comment: I have similar problem in pycharm after upgrading to 3.0. It is the same with javascript code, where some indentation is absolutely illogical and is making automatic indentation useless. Try to contact the support.